# Seeing a custom attribute in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

this is my code and I have added custom attributes in the product edit page.
an attribute for example, the name : id value : 3421

This is my code :

```
<?php
    $size = sizeof( get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_tag' ) );
    echo $product->get_tags( ', ', '<span class="tagged_as">' . _n( 'Tag:', 'Tags:', $size, 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', '.</span>' );
    global $product;
    $attributes = $product->get_attributes();
    echo 'Enter Id Here';
?>
```

and where I echo `enter id here` I want the id to shown.
I tired to reach for the id from the attributes variable I created and it didn't work.
any suggestions?

Comment: What does it show? Is it NULL?

Comment: It simply shows nothing..so i guess its null

Comment: Your code does not show anything, could you edit your question with some more information about your code? Then we can talk about debugging I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$result = array_shift(woocommerce_get_product_terms($product->id, 'pa_koostis', 'names'));
```